# How to store logs in Elasticsearch without using any log shipper like Filebeat or Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I don't want to use filebeat or logstash. I have installed only Elasticsearch and I want to store log records in it and then index them. Is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you can use any [client library](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html) of your choosing and then hit the [Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) endpoint or the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) endpoint to index your data.

Comment: Can you help me out regarding this? I see in the REST API documentation of Elasticsearch that the "Index API" appears twice.... Once under the "Document API" and once under the list of REST APIs directly..... Could you please clarify the difference between them?

Comment: "Document API > Index API" is an API for indexing documents, while "Index API" is an API for managing indexes (create, delete, update settings, etc)